# search form dropdown syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<div class="field">
  <%= line_item.label :quantity %><br>
  <%= line_item.text_field :quantity %>
</div>
```

How can we create a range of quantity from 0 till 10 as a dropdown?

Comment: Give some more info.What are your models and associations?

Comment: Ask questions in more details, don't only use keyways and simple code examples. This question is hard to understand and thereby hard to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your pain. It is hard to figure out. ;-)

Try this code for a 0..10 dropdown:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= line_item.label :quantity %><br>
  <%= line_item.select :quantity, options_for_select(0..10) %>
</div>
```